# Google Play Store is missing (Firebase Authentication)

Tags: java, android, xml, build.gradle, firebase-authentication

I'm beginner for using the Firebase. Currently, I'm trying to do the Firebase Authentication and learnt it from Youtube
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi-UAwiBigQ&index=9&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt)
but it shows me

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
```

Here is my code
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".FireApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AccountActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

FireApp.java

```
package com.google.firebasetester;

import android.app.Application;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;


public class FireApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.google.firebasetester;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;

private Button mLoginBtn;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //FirebaseAuth setup
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

    mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    mAuthListener =new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            //if equal to null means user have not login, cannot find any user
            //if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null)

            //user has login
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         //click when user click on login button
         startSignIn();
     }
    }
    );

}
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
private void startSignIn()
{
    String email=mEmailField.getText().toString();
    String password=mPasswordField.getText().toString();

    //to make sure user not blank the field
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields are empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                //user not successful login
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

AccountActivity.java

```
    package com.google.firebasetester;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
    }
}
```

activity_account.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.google.firebasetester.AccountActivity">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Account"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.google.firebasetester.MainActivity"
    android:padding="20dp">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Password" />

<Button
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordField"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/loginBtn" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Email" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle(Project:FirebaseTester)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebasetester"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[Android Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLcmy.jpg)

Please help me solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had as well the same problem. I've run the application every time on the emulator, were the error occurs. After I run it on a real device, the problem was solved and the login works without any errors.

My tip, try to run it on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because your emulator doesn't have an updated version of Google Play Services. Run the application on your physical phone as GPS updates automatically on that. It might also be because Google Play Services isn't on you emulator.